# Intents with back and up

Tags: android

I (iOS guy) need some help understanding what is going on under the hood when hitting back or up in Android.

Let's assume this setup:

```
ListActivity A --> ListActivity B --> ListActivity C
```

If B has the following line of code:

```
myID = this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("myID");
```

Hitting back or up in C will crash if I do not have:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    Intent backIntent = new Intent(this, B.class);
    backIntent.putExtra("myID", myID);

    startActivity(backIntent);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent backIntent = new Intent(this, B.class);
            backIntent.putExtra("myID", myID);

            startActivity(backIntent);

            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

In ListActivity C when I press either back or up I want: ListActivity C to be destroyed and if the instance of ListActivity B still exists on the stack I want to show it if not I want to recreate it. Right now I think this is the behavior of the back button but if I press up it creates a new instance of ListActivity B that sits on top of ListActivity C so if after pressing up I press back I end up in ListActivity C I want to be back in ListActivity A.

Comment: I do not think you've understood well the activity lifecicle in Android. When you navigate away form an Activity, in your case, from B->C and B gets destroyed (resource shortage, or any other reason), navigating back to it (in the sense of the back button) **will** trigger a new instanciation of that Activity, i.e. Bs `onCreate()` method will be called, in which you have to restore (if needed) its previous state.

Furthermore, you can check if `this.getIntent().getExtras();` is null before doing anything else, which will save you from the crash.

Comment: I understand that what I don't understand is why the up button recreates the activity from scratch and does not even pass a saved instance bundle.

Comment: It shouldn't be doing that. Please check http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html and see if you are missing something

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding singleTop to Activity B in the AndroidManifest?

> If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the target
>   task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to
>   its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance of the
>   activity.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Also, don't forget to finish Activity C if you do not want to go back to it in the next activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    goBack();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            goBack();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void goBack(){
    finish();
    Intent backIntent = new Intent(this, B.class);
    backIntent.putExtra("myID", myID);
    startActivity(backIntent);
}
```

I hope that this will help you out.